How to mimic codable CodingKey in custom encoding
While working on some analytics code in my work project I have been thinking of some optimization I can potentially do.
Let’s say that we have some analytics events conforming to a protocol
protocol AnalyticsEvent {
    var name: String { get }
    var parameters: [String: Any] { get }
}

Let's assume that events are structs like these:
struct SomeEvent: AnalyticsEvent {

    let name: String = "SomeEvent"

    var someParam: String

    var parameters: [String: Any] {
        "someParamKey" : someParam
    }
}

struct SomeOtherEvent: AnalyticsEvent {

    let name: String = "SomeOtherEvent"

    var parameter: String

    var intValue: Int

    var parameters: [String: Any] {
        "parameterKey": parameter,
        "intValueKey" : intValue
    }
}

It kinda works, but doesn't scale since you need to write parameters dictionary for each struct separately.
What I would like to achieve is to mimic CodingKeys from Codable, so I can do like:
protocol AnalyticsEvent {
    associatedtype CodingKeys: Hashable, RawRepresentable
    var name: String { get }
    func encode() -> [String: Any]
}

extension AnalyticsEvent {

    func encode() -> [String: Any] {
        var encoded: [String: Any] = [:]

        ... 
        return encoded
    }
}

then adding some CodingKeys enum that defines key-property mapping like
struct SomeEvent: AnalyticsEvent {

    enum CodingKeys: String {
        case someParam = "someParamKey"
    }

    let name: String

    var someParam: String
}

Is that even a feasible approach? Struct's properites are easily accessible by name via Mirror, but that doesn't seem to be a case for enum cases, so I can't easily use mirror to connect CodingKeys case to property and use its rawValue to fill the result dictionary.
Is there a way to do it that way? Or maybe should I try to write something closer to Codable stack, like JSONDecoder()?
I'm feeling a bit stuck with my idea, probably won't try something super-risky in a prod app, but exploring that seems interesting and I would happily get some keyword or advice how can I push that further.
Thanks!

Looks like you can just write a macro for this. Codable works in a similar way, but instead of a macro, the code generation is just built into the compiler.

The parameters could be generated with a macro. The usage would look something like this:
@GenerateEventParameters
struct SomeOtherEvent: AnalyticsEvent {

    let name = "SomeOtherEvent"
    
    @Parameter("parameterKey")
    var parameter: String

    @Parameter("intValueKey")
    var intValue: Int
}

GenerateEventParameters is a MemberMacro that generates the parameters property. Parameter doesn't expand to anything and just acts as a marker for the GenerateEventParameters macro to read.
(The name Parameter is also used in TipKit. If you are using TipKit somewhere, consider renaming it to something else)
An example implementation:
// declarations
@attached(peer)
public macro Parameter(_ name: String) = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "AnalyticsEventParameterMacro")
@attached(member, names: named(parameters))
public macro GenerateEventParameters() = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "GenerateEventParametersMacro")

// implementation
enum AnalyticsEventParameterMacro: PeerMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        []
    }
}

enum GenerateEventParametersMacro: MemberMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        providingMembersOf declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        var mapping: [String: TokenSyntax] = [:]
        for member in declaration.memberBlock.members {
            guard let propDecl = member.decl.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self),
                  let paramAttr = propDecl.attributes.findAttribute("Parameter"),
                  case let .argumentList(args) = paramAttr.arguments,
                  let paramName = args.first?.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)?.representedLiteralValue,
                  let propName = propDecl.bindings.first?.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?.identifier
            else { continue }
            mapping[paramName] = propName
        }
        let dictLiteral = DictionaryExprSyntax {
            for (key, value) in mapping {
                DictionaryElementSyntax(
                    key: StringLiteralExprSyntax(content: key),
                    value: DeclReferenceExprSyntax(baseName: value)
                )
            }
        }
        return [
            """
            var parameters: [String: Any] {
                \(dictLiteral)
            }
            """
        ]
    }
}


extension AttributeListSyntax {
    func findAttribute(_ name: String) -> AttributeSyntax? {
        for elem in self {
            if case let .attribute(attr) = elem,
                attr.attributeName.as(IdentifierTypeSyntax.self)?.name.text == name {
                return attr
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

@main
struct YourMacroPlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [
        AnalyticsEventParameterMacro.self,
        GenerateEventParametersMacro.self
    ]
}

I did not include any error messages in this simple implementation. If something isn't what it is expecting, it will just do nothing and likely cause a compiler error. Here are some cases that you should detect and emit an appropriate message that I can think of:

duplicate parameter keys
applying @Parameter multiple times on a single property
not using a string literal as the argument of @Parameter

For how to emit error messages, see my post here.

Also consider generating the whole protocol conformance using a macro, so that you don't have type let name = ... or : AnalyticsEvent anymore. The name property could be passed as an argument to the member macro. The usage would be similar to @Observable in Observation.
// declaration
@attached(extension, conformances: AnalyticsEvent, names: named(name), named(parameters))
public macro AnalyticsEvent(_ name: String) = #externalMacro(module: "...", type: "AnalyticsEventMacro")

// implementation
enum AnalyticsEventMacro: ExtensionMacro {
    static func expansion(
        of node: AttributeSyntax,
        attachedTo declaration: some DeclGroupSyntax,
        providingExtensionsOf type: some TypeSyntaxProtocol,
        conformingTo protocols: [TypeSyntax],
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) throws -> [ExtensionDeclSyntax] {
        guard let name = declaration.asProtocol(NamedDeclSyntax.self)?.name else { return [] }
        guard case let .argumentList(args) = node.arguments,
              let eventName = args.first?.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)
        else { return [] }
        
        var mapping: [String: TokenSyntax] = [:]
        for member in declaration.memberBlock.members {
            guard let propDecl = member.decl.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self),
                  let paramAttr = propDecl.attributes.findAttribute("Parameter"),
                  case let .argumentList(args) = paramAttr.arguments,
                  let paramName = args.first?.expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self)?.representedLiteralValue,
                  let propName = propDecl.bindings.first?.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)?.identifier
            else { continue }
            mapping[paramName] = propName
        }
        let dictLiteral = DictionaryExprSyntax {
            for (key, value) in mapping {
                DictionaryElementSyntax(
                    key: StringLiteralExprSyntax(content: key),
                    value: DeclReferenceExprSyntax(baseName: value)
                )
            }
        }
        return [
            try ExtensionDeclSyntax("extension \(name): AnalyticsEvent") {
                """
                var parameters: [String: Any] {
                    \(dictLiteral)
                }
                """
                """
                var name: String { \(eventName) }
                """
            }
        ]
    }
}

// usage:

@AnalyticsEvent("SomeOtherEvent")
struct SomeOtherEvent {
    @Parameter("parameterKey")
    var parameter: String

    @Parameter("intValueKey")
    var intValue: Int
}


Wow :) Thank you for a detailed and inspiring answer. Will be happy to try and play with macros after such a detailed intro I received:)
